# getting 401 axios error when I am trying to print data using stripe api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

This is my api.js file which is calling stripe api

```
import axios from 'axios';

const params = {
    headers:{
        Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP,
    }
};

export const fetchDataFromApi = async (url) => {
    try{
        const{data} = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URL + url, params);
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    }
    catch(e){ 
        console.log(e)
        return e;
    }
}
```

this is my home.js file which is calling api.js file method in order to print api data on console

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
  }, []);

  co
```

but it is only showing

> {"data":null,"error":{"status":401,"name":"UnauthorizedError","message":"Missing or invalid credentials","details":{}}}

I have checked my api key and url, both are correct.